# .each() function on affect current object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

having some issues with my code below, first here is the HTML:

```
<table class="finance-table">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Deposit</th>
    <th>Balance</th>
    <th>Fees</th>
    <th>Total Payable</th>
    <th>Term</th>
    <th>Fixed Rate</th>
    <th>Representative APR</th>

    <th>Monthly Pmt</th>

  </tr>
  <tr class="hp">
    <td><strong>HP</strong></td>
    <td id="td_finance_deposit">£11700.00</td>
    <td id="td_finance_balance">£105300.00</td>
    <td id="td_finance_fees">£298.00</td>
    <td id="td_finance_total_inc_deposit">£146255.50</td>
    <td id="td_finance_term">60 mths</td>
    <td id="td_finance_rate">5.50%</td>
    <td id="td_finance_apr">10.1%</td>

    <td id="td_finance_monthly_payments">£2242.59 p/m*  x 60 mths</td>

  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

There is about 10 of these tables [within the same document], all with the same id's and class's. I'm using an each loop to execute some code against each table found, however it only seems to be working on the first table and disregards the others.

Below is the jQuery, like I said works find on the first table, but ignores the rest!

```
<!-- Remove First and Final Payment from Showroom Finance Examples -->
<script>
  $(".finance-table").each(function(key, value) {
    // Display loading
    var html = $(this);

    // Remove the First Payment and Final Payment Column
    $(this).find("#td_finance_first_payment, #td_finance_final_payment").remove();
    $(this).find("th:contains('1st Pmt')").remove(); $(this).find("th:contains('Final Pmt')").remove();

    // Get the Term and update the monthly payment
    var term = $(this).find("#td_finance_term").html(); // .replace(/\D/g,'')
    var payments = ($(this).find("#td_finance_monthly_payments").html()).split('x')[0];
    ($(this).find("#td_finance_monthly_payments")).html(payments + " x " + term);
  })
</script>
```

Edit: 
**Please note, I can't change the HTML at all**

Comment: Id be unique in HTML. Please make sure id be unique in your code

Comment: Seems you are using same identifiers multiple times

Comment: You may say you can't change the HTML, but if you have duplicate id's on the page its not valid HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first give a unique ID to each `<td>`, perhaps with your DB identifier for that record.  You don't need it now but this will allow you to do other thing later if you need it.

Then change all the `<td>` ids to classes:

```
<td class="td_finance_fees">£298.00</td>
```

Finally change all your javascript accordingly to use class instead of IDs:

```
$(this).find(".td_finance_first_payment, .td_finance_final_payment").remove();
```

Comment: I can't change any of the HTML, sorry forgot to mention this.

Comment: @MartynBall If you can't edit the broken HTML, then chances are, you won't be able to do what you're trying to do. (At least without some seriously nasty work-arounds)

Comment: I would try first to find a way to change that HTML.  I understand that maybe you are extracting it from another URL you don't have control over it or maybe from a generated document from another app.  In that case then go for @viion's simple workaround.  Very clever and resourceful. I'm adding that to my arsenal.

Comment: I have managed to get the dev team to add a unique ID to each table, thanks ! :D

Comment: Good that you managed to convince the devs to produce valid html. Point them here if they're not sure: https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 3):

Using [Attribute Equals Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Change your code from:

```
$(this).find("#td_finance_first_payment, #td_finance_final_payment").remove();
```

to:

```
$(this).find('td[id="td_finance_first_payment"], td[id="td_finance_final_payment"]').remove();
```

Do this type of change for all areas of `#xxx` to `id="xxx"`

What this does is find all tds with attribute id="xxx", rather than using #id identifier, this is forces jQuery to do a tree search.

Also your HTML does not match your code, (theres no td_finance_first_payment in your html, I assume you removed it?)

Edit: This solution is useful if you 100% cannot edit the html (comes from a source you have no control over, such as an API or internal software). Best solution would be to fix the ids!

Comment: +1 I didn't know of this workaround. I also assume he pasted the "processed" table's source. So it doesn't have any of the elements he mentions in the jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for that, going to change the HTML but that is good to know